# Using Spring Batch with a webapp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch

I currently have an use case where I need to use Spring Batch to download a series of publicly available images from the web to use in an image gallery. While downloading the images and related meta-data using Spring Batch is trivial, I want to be able to download these images to a directory that is accessible by the webapp (possibly written using Spring MVC) that will use them. I'm currently resorting to absolute paths to do this and was wondering if there is a way within Spring to use relative paths instead. Please help...

Answer (score 1):

you can place your image directory path in a properties / xml configuration file which is read by the web-app, such as if you need to relocate in the future you can just change it

Comment: Thanks Gerry. I'm currently doing something similar (absolute paths are maintained in an XML config file). I was however wondering if there is a way to get a relative path via code - similar to how you would get a relative path to image/css/js resources in a webapp..

Comment: You can use `ServletContext.getResource()`